# insert multiple images in db

Tags: php, mysql

i have a form that puts one image in the db, I would like to put multiple at once. i have a multiple input in my form. I've seen here similar topics but it didn't help.

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="files" name="photo" required multiple>
```

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if (isset($_FILES['photo'])){   


            include 'dbconnect.php';


              $target = "img/"; //This is the directory where images will be saved 
              $target_file = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); //This gets all the other information from the form

            $ad_user = $_POST['user_id'];
            $ad_phone = $_POST['telephone'];
            $ad_title = $_POST['title'];
            $ad_price = $_POST['price'];
            $ad_categorie = $_POST['category'];
            $ad_city = $_POST['ville'];
            $ad_pays = $_POST['pays'];
            $ad_description = $_POST['description'];
            $ad_photo= $target . ($_FILES['photo']['name']);               


                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) { //Tells you if its all ok 

                    } else { //Gives and error if its not 

                          echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
                    }

                  $sql = "INSERT INTO ads (title, price, description, city, pays, urlimage, user, phone, category) VALUES ('$ad_title', '$ad_price', '$ad_description','$ad_city', '$ad_pays', '$ad_photo', '$ad_user', '$ad_phone', '$ad_categorie ') ";
                  $conn->query($sql);
                  //Writes the photo to the server

                  header('db.php'); 

$conn->close();

          }
    }
```

?>

this is my file input in the form and the php. can someone help? thanx

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you are simply ASSUMING that uploads and queries never fail. Both are extremely bad attitudes to have. Never EVER assume success. always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise. `$_FILES` has a `['error']` parameter for a reason - check it.

Comment: You're also doing absolutely no checking on the file name passed in. What if it's hostile? Someone could over-write chunks of your application with this code.

Comment: @Marc B thanx guys for the security heads up, i'll check that right away but still no answaer to the actual question...

Comment: and the question is? HOW is this not working?

Comment: for one image it's working fine but i would like to upload more than one